# To find difference in two files using diff shell command using system() in c program

Tags: c, shell, diff

I am finding difficult to redirect the difference in two files using diff inside system (), tried all permutation and combinations but failed.

```
status = system("/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/diff old_ap.json ap_afterTtime.json |tr -d '<> ---,'> diffoutput");
```

The error:

> /usr/bin/diff: missing operand after '/usr/bin/diff'
>
> /usr/bin/diff: Try '/usr/bin/diff --help' for more information.

Tried to use absolute path of two input files  but the output file remains blank. Though,every time output file is written but blank.
I am trying to read two Json files and found difference in the data written and store in a file.

Comment: remove /bin/sh -c and try again

Comment: This is more of a sh programming question than a C question, but: the command after `-c` must be a single argument.  So if you wanted to use `-c` — and, it's true, sometimes you have to — you'd need the equivalent of `/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/diff old_ap.json ap_afterTtime.json |tr -d '<> ---,'> diffoutput"`, but in order to pass that to `system()` you'd need to quote the quotes, and it would get messy.  So the suggestion to try it without the `sh -c` is a good one.

Comment: Have tried without /bin/sh -c but output remains same. This is a workaround to save some coding, this is just a part of a task which i am trying to accomplish. This works flawless on shell ,from which i derived the concept to achieve a diffoutput.

Comment: What OS?  If Linux, run your command under `strace -f -o /path/to/strace/output/file.txt ...`.  Then look for the `execv*()` for `diff` and `tr` (if `tr` even gets `exec()`'d...) and see what argument(s) are actually getting passed to `diff` and `tr`.  The [POSIX `system()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/system.html) has a pretty good explanation of how `sysytem()` behaves on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this program, to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/diff old_ap.json ap_afterTtime.json |tr -d '<> ---,'> diffoutput");
}
```

I got the error `missing operand after '/usr/bin/diff'`, as reported.

The problem is that when you use `sh -c`, the command after `-c` must be a single argument.

I don't think `-c` is needed here, so I changed the `system` call to

```
    system("/usr/bin/diff old_ap.json ap_afterTtime.json |tr -d '<> ---,'> diffoutput");
```

and the error went away, and a file `diffoutput` was created.

For completeness, I also tried

```
    system("/bin/sh -c \"/usr/bin/diff old_ap.json ap_afterTtime.json |tr -d '<> ---,'> diffoutput\"");
```

This retains the `-c`, but uses extra quotes so that `-c` sees the entire command as a single argument.  This also worked.

You said that removing `sh -c` did not help, so there must be something different about your environment.  What operating system are you running under?

Comment: Technical detail: repeating the `-` in the `tr` command arguments doesn't help (or hinder) the command.  The output in `diffoutput` will be indecipherable; all the spaces (and commas, dashes and angle brackets) will have been removed, leaving numbers and words run together.  I'm not keen on the `> diffoutput` not having a space before the `>`.  However, that's a feature of the code in the question.

Comment: That works; when i used usr/bin/diff ,i was infact overriding old_ap.json with ap_afterTtime.json,thus making it same and hence the output was blank. Thanks for your help. Thank you everyone for your time.